# adding a * or changing the background (groupbox) color when dirty flag is up for changed textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, event-handling

I have a groupbox with a background of a certain color containing a textbox. I was thinking of ways to help the user see that the textbox was dirty, and thought perhaps changing the background groupbox color and/or adding a "*" to the name of the groupbox and/or Form Text would be nice. But I can't get the event to even change the property of _isDirty. Let alone implement this idea. I'm sure that someone has done something similar and Hope that you could help me. I'm working with C# .Net framework 2.0 (it should also work in 4.0 but that's backwards compatible I believe). IDE is Visual Studios 10.

The idea is when the textbox is changed, the _isDirty "flag"/"property" will be changed, as well as when it has been saved:

_isDirty = true when textbox has been changed

_isDirty = false when textbox has been saved

This is what I have at the moment.. though I've tried different things including the INotify which wasn't working for me at all...

```
    public static bool _isDirty = false;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newtext = textBox1.Text;
        if (currentText != newtext)
        {
            // This solves the problem of initial text being tagged as changed text
            if (currentText == "")
            {
                _isDirty = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //OnIsDirtyChanged();
                _isDirty = true; //might have to change with the dirty marker
            }
            currentText = newtext;
        }
    }

     public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return _isDirty; }
        set
        {
            if (_isDirty != value)
            {
                _isDirty = value;
                OnIsDirtyChanged(_isDirty);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnIsDirtyChanged(bool _isDirty)
    {
        if (_isDirty == true)
        {
            this.Text += "*";
        }
    }
```

If someone has a different suggestion to how I go about this, or a nicer user friendly way of doing this, I'm open for suggestions.. Thanks!

EDIT: The answer is actually in 2 parts! The correction to make the property change event WORK was given by BRAM. 
If you want to know how to change background color, then look at ZARATHOS'S answer. 
Unfortunately I can only mark ONE answer, so going to mark the one that got the main bit working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting _isDirty so the event does not fire.
You need to set IsDirty.

```
    if (currentText != newtext)
    {
        // This solves the problem of initial text being tagged as changed text
        if (currentText == "")
        {
            IsDirty = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //OnIsDirtyChanged();
            IsDirty = true; //might have to change with the dirty marker
        }
        currentText = newtext;
    }
```

And this line is wrong

```
OnIsDirtyChanged(_isDirty);
```

Needs to be

```
OnIsDirtyChanged(IsDirty);
```

Assuming that is the notification event.

Comment: I see, I get the * now... thanks a million! Now to get the UI to reflect it to be noticeable..

Comment: Don't follow.  If you get the * now what else do you want?

Comment: well actually I was also looking for a color change, but both You and Zarathos helped me with this. I would like to give you both the answer.. is that possible? It works now.

Comment: As for the background I would do that with a DataTrigger on IsDirty in the XAML

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to change the textbox background to a light red color (and eventually also changing the text to keep readability) without touching the groupbox which is just a container element and its integrity should be preserved in order to avoid confusing users. If the problem is in the textbox, highlight the textbox.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newtext = textBox1.Text;

    if (currentText != newtext)
    {
        if (currentText == "")
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        currentText = newtext;
    }
}
```

You don't need anything else.

Comment: That sounds like a good suggestion. Can you help me with coding it? and activating the event as the * isn't even working, and I thought adding a * would be easy! lol

Comment: Please be more detailed on when a textbox should be considered "dirty" and I'll provide some code in my answer.

Comment: If the user has entered and/or changed the content of the textbox (not just put the cursor there, but a real text change (newtext != oldtext)) then the property _isDirty should be set to true. When this property has changed, the UI should reflect that. Like turning light red background for example.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code. I think it's on now unless there are logical problems in your approach.

Comment: It works like a charm, together with Blam's correction :) Now I have 2 different problems, but I can move forward!